# List all forecast CSV files exported to AWS S3 bucket when using AWS Forecast Export Job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, forecasting, amazon-forecast

I have trained a Predictor on AWS Forecast, and used it to make some forecasts.
I want to get these forecasts as CSV files. To do so, I created a "ForecastExportJob".
After the exportation is done, I can successfully see the CSV files in my S3 bucket.

I would like to download them programmatically, so is there a way to have a list of S3 keys that correspond to the CSV files created with the "ForecastExportJob" command?

I could list all objects in the destination buckets and filter them, but I am wondering if there is a "more elegant" solution to my problem.

[image: AWS S3 bucket content after calling AWS ForecastExportJob]

Put it simply, I would like to know if there is an AWS command that can list the files created by the "ForecastExportJob" command:

- electricityforecast_export_job_2021-01-04T06-40-23Z_part0.csv
- ...
- electricityforecast_export_job_2021-01-04T06-40-23Z_part7.csv

Note: I am using boto3

Thank you in advance and happy new year!